# How to query for a single field in firestore 9

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query the doc for data. I found out how to query using the flowing logic

```
const docRefCol = doc(db, 'UsersCollection', uid);

interface objectData {
   field1Obj: { [key: string]: any };
   field2Arr: [];
 }

 let obj: objectData = { field1Obj: {}, field2Arr: [] };
  await getDoc(docRefCol).then((docSnap) => {
   Object.assign(obj, docSnap.data());  
 });
  
  console.log(obj)
```

The issue with this is I want an immutable way to extract data. Plus anther way to query for single field (let's say `field1Obj`), rather than calling the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to get a few fields (at least not in client SDKs). But you can destruct the object and get the fields you need (or filter in case you are querying multiple objects).

```
let obj: objectData = { field1Obj: {}, field2Arr: [] };

await getDoc(docRefCol).then((docSnap) => {
  const { field1Object, field2Arr, ...rest } = docSnap.data()
  obj = { field1Object, field2Arr }
});
```

In case of a QuerySnapshot, it could be like:

```
await getDocs(query).then((querySnap) => {
  const docs = querySnap.docs.map((doc) => {
    const { field1Object, field2Arr, ...rest } = doc.data()
    return { field1Object, field2Arr }
  })
});
```

It surely won't reduce amount of data being fetched from database but selecting fields is currently supported by Admin/server side SDKs only.